# Data Privacy with Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, privacy

I've recently begun using Tensorflow via Keras and Python 3.5 to analyze company data, and I am by no means an expert and only recently built my first "real-world" model.

With my experimental data I used Tensorboard to visualiza how my neural network was working, and I would like to do the same with my real data. However, my company is extremely strict about company data leaving our servers -  so my question is this:

Does tensorboard take the raw data used in the model and upload it off-site to generate its reports/visuals or does it only use processed data/results from my model?

I've done several google searches already, and I haven't found anything conclusive one way or the other.

If I'm not asking this question correctly, please let me know - I'm new to all of this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tensorboard does not upload the data to "the cloud" or anywhere outside the computer where it is running, it just interprets data produced by the model.